# Python Data Structures for programming contest

Tags: python, c++, data-structures

What are the equivalent data structures in Python of those in C++? As a contestant I have always used C++ STL in programming contests. So, vector,set,map,queue,priority queue,pair all of these came in handy. Recently, I tried to solve a few problems using python. But could not find same structures. So, what are the similar data structures in Python? If not available, what are the tricks to implement those?

Comment: C++=> Python
Map => Dict, Set => Set, Vector =>List, Pair=>Tuple
No idea about queue and such

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List, set and map (called dictionary), are built-in in python. For others see the `collections` module (especially the `collections.deque` is suitable for queues)

Comment: Thanks for your time. As I looked in the documentation, Set does store unique elements but not in sorted order. In c++, both insert and delete operation in Set costs (log(n)) time complexity and also keep them sorted. Is there any way to do the same?

Comment: There is no such thing in the standard libraries, set is unordered as per the mathematical definition. I can think of two ways to make one: one is to use collections.OrderedDict (which is a hashmap that keeps the keys in the order they were inserted) and ignore the values. The other, is to use this http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576694/ recipe, which is mentioned it the python documentation itself